# Types for 'Array.prototype.find()' with an array deconstructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to destruct an array, but I am getting the following errors:

> Type 'undefined' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

```
let [alias, config]: [string, DBConfig] | undefined = Object.entries(info).find(...)
```

This is what the `find` definition shows, it is the same as what I defined.

```
(method) Array<[string, DBConfig]>.find(predicate: (
  value: [string, DBConfig], 
  index: number, 
  obj: [string, DBConfig][]) => boolean, thisArg?: any
): [string, DBConfig] | undefined (+1 overload)
```

If I remove my definition so it looks like this:

```
let [alias, config] = Object.entries(info).find(...)
```

I then get the same error. What can I do (without using `any`) to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem comes down to the fact that you're trying to use destructuring on something that might not be destrcturable (e.g. `undefined`).

If you are sure `let [alias, config] = Object.entries(info).find(...)` will **never** result in `undefined` in your use cases then you just have to cast it :

```
let [alias, config] = Object.entries(info).find(/*...*/) as [string | DBConfig];
```

If it **may** result in `undefined` then you will have to accept a nullable DBConfig

```
let [alias, config] = Object.entries(info).find(/*...*/) || ["", null];
```